# Кастомный вариант форматирования строки .toString("D4")

Tags: c#, строки

Есть данные типа int

```
int someX = 11;
int someY = 105;
...
```

Нужно получать конвертировать их в строку определенной длины с пробелами перед значением.
Если использовать .toString("D4"), то он добавляет нули в недостающие символы

```
someX.toString("D4");
// Вывод "0011"
// А нужен "  11"
```

Есть ли простое решение как это можно сделать без циклов перебора символов?
Или может можно переопределить базовый функционал и заменить в нем 0 на символ пробела?

Comment: Причина  для такого форматирования, отправка данных по сокету на устройство которое принимает данные в определенном формате. Может кто знает фреймворк или библиотеку которая подходит для работы с производственными машинами по сокету?

Comment: `someX.ToString().PadLeft(4)`, `string.Format("{0,4}", someX)`, `$"{someX,4}"`

Comment: `String.Format("{0,4:D}", someX)`, работает ли такой формат с `toString` я не знаю, проверьте.